# Esconder o cerrar jFrame en condición(al ejecutar)

Tags: java

Quiero que cuando ejecute el programa si hay dicho archivo esconda la ventana y si no y la deje abierta por ejemplo así no se me oculta con el this.setVisible(false) se debería de esconder pero si le meto eso a un boton si lo esconde(inclusive trate con .dispose()).

```
public Menu() throws IOException {
    initComponents();
    if(met1()){
        Ventana v = new Ventana ();
        v.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Prueba con `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` a ver si te sirve

Comment: Sigue abriendose cave destacar que la ventana que quiero cerrar o esconder es la principal

Comment: Quieres esconder o cerrar el jframe?

Comment: Cualquiera de las 2 me sirve como dije eh usado this.visible(false) y this.dispose() y ninguno me funciona si lo ejecuto desde donde esta ese codigo que puse.